# SSH hanging after accepting public key

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm getting strange behavior from ssh. I'm trying to log in to an ssh user named 'nfs' (e.g. `ssh nfs@example.com`) and it accepts the public key, but hangs.

The contents of `ssh -vvv` immediately following the connection are as follows.

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to [REDACTED].
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env TERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env APPLICATION_ENV
debug3: Ignored env JAVA_HOME
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env SECURITYSESSIONID
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

So it looks like it *does* accept the key and connects, but it's not giving a prompt. I can log in as another user, and su into the 'nfs' user (and I get a bash prompt), so I know the user config is fine. But something is preventing a direct ssh connection. I'm not sure what these log entries mean. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the shell specified for user nfs in your /etc/passwd file?

Comment: Just curious, when you test this by first logging in as another user and then switching accounts, rather than using `su nfs`, what happens if you use `login nfs`? I'm wondering if `su` isn't really performing full login process. `su -l nfs` tries to do a full login, but it seems like actually running `login` is even more real.

Comment: It's set to /bin/bash. And yes, I can `login` into the 'nfs' user and it works just fine. I just needed to set a temporary password and log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `debug1: Remote: Forced command.` suggests that the public key you logged in with specifies a command to be run, so you won't get a shell. Check the `nfs` user's `authorized_keys` file and see if the key you're using has a `command="command"` directive attached. If so, you'll have to remove that, or use a different keypair, or use password auth, etc.

Comment: This was it! Thanks! It looks like the sysadmins for this server does have a command specified with the SSH key (they set the shell to /bin/sleep 7d). I apparently just learned that this is all pointless anyway, since these SSH sessions are just used to forward ports and no shell is needed.